# How to solve cast not valid when Get a Specific Column Value from a DataTable in this example in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

my data table comeback any row with 2 column contain product id and product name.

product id in the tables on DB is nvarchar(150)

product name is nvarchar(150)

example:(in dt_ProductName)

```
product id                        product name
----------                        ------------
  1                                 a 300
  3                                 2 200
```

** when text is equal "a 300" return product Model_ID= 1

I want to get product id when value column product name = text.
(for sql = select product id from tbl-product where product name = @productname)

product id` must only one value.
text is string and enter by user telegram

```
string Model_Names = text.tostring();

Decimal Model_ID = (from DataRow DR in dt_ProductName.Rows
                     where (string)DR["ProductName"]== Model_Names 
                     select (decimal) DR["ProductID"]).FirstOrDefault();
```

> Specified cast is not valid.

when used this code:

```
 for (int xx = 0; xx > dt_ProductName.Rows.Count;xx++ )
 {
     if (dt_ProductName.Rows[xx][1].ToString() == Model_Names)
     {
          Model_ID = (decimal)dt_ProductName.Rows[xx][0];
     }
     else
     {
          continue;
     }
 }
```

for not work, only check count and xx but not check if?!

Comment: Well, what type is `ProductID`?

Comment: If ProductID is a nvarchar you can't cast it to a decimal but you need to convert it

Comment: There must be at least 1 DR["ProductID"]) is not decimal.

Comment: This begs the question why the `ProductId` is a varchar at all. Make it an `int` column

Comment: How do I convert steve?

Comment: Hint: `decimal.Parse(DR["ProductID"]);` And yes, why your ID is nvarchar and even why you try to cast it to decimal? Use integer in DB and in code.

Comment: Also why to run all that LINQ? Just return the valid, single value of ProductID from the database. I  guess that should be possible to access it based on index (DataRow [0] ?)

Comment: dear @TimSchmelter, The person who designed the database was wrong and I do not have access to change

Comment: @cyrus2500: then talk to the person who is responsible for this mess. Maybe he had a reason for this, then you should not convert it to `decimal` but keep it as string. If he had no reason he should change it.

Comment: `for (int xx = 0; xx > dt_ProductName.Rows.Count;xx++ )` will not execute even once. Why are you using `>` and not `<`?

Comment: @Reniuz , all id in db is numeric but in tbl is nvarchar. when use decimal.Parse(DR["ProductID"]) this error :  > Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'decimal.Parse(string)' has some invalid argument

Comment: oh my god @sefe , I got confused:(( . thats right.

Comment: @cyrus2500: the indexer returns an object, you need to use `decimal.Parse(DR.Field<string>("ProductID"))`

Comment: You get this error because `Decimal.Parse` expects a string, while your data row provides an `object`. Either cast to string first or use `Convert` as in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why the `ProductId` is a `varchar` at all? Make it an `int` column. If you can't do that you should talk to the person who is responsible. he can tell you if he had a reason for this, maybe the `ProductId` can be `"ABC1234"` now or in future. Otherwise he might change it before all your code depends on the wrong type.

However, you can use `decimal.TryParse` to safely convert the string to decimal.

```
DataRow row = dt_ProductName.AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("ProductName") == Model_Names);
decimal Model_ID = -1;
if(row != null && decimal.TryParse(row.Field<string>("ProductId"), out Model_ID))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Product {Model_Names} found, ProductId = {Model_ID}");
}
```

Comment: thanks Tim , id is all tbl is numeric and no charachter in the id at all db.

Answer (score 5):

You can't cast a string into a decimal with `(decimal)DR["ProductID"]`. That is a typecast, which is not supported by string *or* decimal.

You have to use `Convert.ToDecimal`:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(DR["ProductID"])
```

Comment: If he who designed the database had a reason for making `ProductID` a varchar-column you should better use `decimal.TryParse`.

Comment: That is a valid option, but would be dependent on the requirements. Since `DR` is a `DataRow`, you would still have to cast to string first, before you can `TryParse`.

Comment: Thanks my friends for your all tips

Comment: All solution thats good and work , thanks all friends and sorry for Question amateur. I did not convert the specialized knowledge. I knew that I would be the only cause of the convert. reference for me about convert ?

Answer (score 4):

Basically what Sefe wrote is correct, but you have a more severe issue in your code than just the obvious run-time exception. The `product id` is saved as a `nvarchar(150)` in your model. This can be justified, undoubtly.

Anyway, the `Model_ID` in your code is a `Decimal` (which would be okay, too, even though I'd go with an `ulong`). Your property that you are using to refer to the `product id` has a completely different type (string-ish type vs. numerical type). If you are using Sefe's solution you'd probably do fine for now, given that all your `product id`s are convertible to `Decimal`, but you will run into a new run-time issue as soon as anybody decides

> Hey, we can enter an arbitrary string into that ID column. Lets enter asdfg1234 as an ID

The solution would be to fit the types. Either both string-ish (`nvarchar` and `string`) or both numerical (whatever types suit your needs and are supported by your platforms).

Comment: That's correct (+1 for that). Maybe OP is just trying to make the best of a bad situation he can't change. Who hasn't been in the situation where the _right_ solution is out there, but you have to go with a dirty solution to fix a problem you haven't caused and you can't change?